# Как избавиться от дублирования в URL

Tags: seo, php, html

Заметил что в поисковиках можно встретить URL моего сайта в таком виде: вместо http://site.ru/blog/article/25 получается http://site.ru/blog/article/blog/article/blog/article/blog/article/blog/article/blog/article/blog/article/blog/article/25

В мета прописан base url: `<base href="/">`

Ссылки прописываю так: `<a href="blog/article/25"></a>`

Может быть стоит прописывать ссылки так: `<a href="/blog/article/25` 
(Добавил / в начале ссылки)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучшее решение конечно писать полный URL, либо чтобы не было таких больших дубликатов начинать нужно с "/" - как правило толчок идет от вашего основного URL

Comment: Спасибо, теперь будет спокойнее. В любом случае я уже подставил "/". Так что буду ждать результата.